# Lambda returning a reference causes a segmentation fault - why?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, crash, segmentation-fault

The following code is taken [straight out of one of my projects](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVOpenHexagon/blob/JSONTest/include/SSVOpenHexagon/Online/OHServer.h). The first version causes a crash (segmentation fault). The second version works as intended.

**Aren't the two code snippets equivalent?**

---

*This one crashes*

```
auto getUserFromPacket = [&](sf::Packet& mP) -> User& 
{ 
    return users.getUser(ssvuj::as<std::string>(getDecompressedPacket(mP), 0)); 
};
pHandler[FromClient::US_Death] = [&](ClientHandler&, sf::Packet& mP)        
{
    getUserFromPacket(mP).stats.deaths += 1; // segmentation fault here!
};
```

---

*This one works*

```
pHandler[FromClient::US_Death] = [&](ClientHandler&, sf::Packet& mP)        
{
    users.getUser(ssvuj::as<std::string>(getDecompressedPacket(mP), 0)).stats.deaths += 1; 
    // this works fine
};
```

---

Compiler used: *clang++ 3.4* - it also couldn't deduce the return type of `getUserFromPacket`. `users` is an instance of an `UserDB`. The function signature is `User& UserDB::getUser(const std::string&)` - why does the compiler fail to deduce `User&` as the return type?

Comment: Does `getUserFromPacket` still exist when `pHandler[...]` is called?

Comment: @GManNickG: I feel unbelievably stupid right now. I was capturing `getUserFromPacket` by reference, and its lifetime was too short. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Happens to everyone. :)

Comment: `[&]` is almost always a bad idea - if you want to capture by reference, be explicit.

Comment: Also, any idea why clang couldn't deduce the return type?

Comment: If the type of `users.getUser(ssvuj::as<std::string>(getDecompressedPacket(mP), 0))` is `User&`, the return type of the lambda should deduce `User`.

Comment: @casey it is a bad idea if the closure(or copies) may outlast the scope it is created in.  Otherwise, it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't equivalent. The first one will refer to the lambda, which (likely) will not be in scope by the time it is needed. The second has no such dependency. Always be careful capturing by reference. :)